# Does `#pragma GCC system_header` in a header file extend into another source or header file that includes it?

Tags: c++, gcc, preprocessor, translation-unit

I need to disable all warnings inside a certain header file, and only that file only.
The version of my compiler is `g++-4.8`. I have to use that compiler.

I looked up in the documentation of that compiler:
[g++-4.8 documentation support for System-Headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/cpp/System-Headers.html#System-Headers)

It is written:

> All warnings, other than those generated by `#warning`, are suppressed while GCC is processing a system header. Macros defined in a system header are immune to a few warnings wherever they are expanded.

> There is also a directive, `#pragma GCC system_header`, which tells GCC to consider the rest of the current include file a system header, no matter where it was found. Code that comes before the `#pragma` in the file will not be affected. **`#pragma GCC system_header` has no effect in the primary source file.**

As English is my second language, it is not clear to me what **that last sentence** means.

I want to disable all the warnings in the entire **single** header file. This header file is included by many different C++ source code files `*.cpp`. This header file is also included by several other header files `*.h`, and those header files are also included by other files.

I want to know, if I put the `#pragma GCC system_header` in the **single** header file, will the effect of that `#pragma` directive be transferred into any file that includes that header? Because I do not want to disable any warnings in the files which include this header file. I want to disable warnings only for the structures *which are defined in that header file only*.

So in other words, does the effect of the `#pragma GCC system_header` applies to the entire translation unit (I don't want that) or only to that single header file like in a text editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a reaffirmation of the main rule:

> There is also a directive, #pragma GCC system_header, which tells GCC to consider **the rest of the current include file** a system header

That's it. Not other headers, not the file where you wrote `#include`.

Just that file.

Comment: Ah thank you for explaining or confirming this. I think that the documentation is a somewhat vague.

Comment: What happens when a header file becomes a system header? Does it include system calls or so?